# Autosize width of text beside textarea?

Tags: html, css, autosize

I want to display a textarea for user input and to the right of it I want to display an instruction text. I want the instructions text to use the available width beside the text area and I want its lines to wrap as necessary, but stay to the right of the textarea. I'd like the text to be top aligned with the text area.

```
<div class="container">
  <textarea rows="10" cols="30">Text data</textarea>
  <div class="instructions">
    Please follow these instructions when entering data 
    into the textarea to the left. Blah blah blah..
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I achieve this with HTML5 and CSS3 that works in most modern browsers?

EDIT: Perhaps I should add that I tried setting both `textarea` and `div.instructions` to `display: inline-block`, but that's not enough because the `div.instructions` doesn't wrap. Instead, when the available space to the right of the `textarea` is too small to fit the instructions text on a single line, the entire `div.instructions` slips below the `textarea`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0bh0mLej/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell`:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="display: table-cell">
      <textarea rows="10" cols="30">Text data</textarea>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
    Please follow these instructions when entering data 
    into the textarea to the left. Blah blah blah..
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. But I found it to work if I also set div.container to display: table-row.

Comment: Does it? Not for me in Chrome. Can you test this JSFiddle please? With/without the `display: table-row` row commented out?
http://jsfiddle.net/0bh0mLej/2/

Comment: Your JSFiddle does not correspond to my code.  My code works if you click "Run code snippet", at least in Chrome.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you wrapped the `textarea` in a `div`. Any idea why that makes all the difference?

Comment: I don't think textarea can be made to behave as a table cell.  I only use divs for layout issues, since they can take on those display styles.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.form-block {
  display: table;
}
.f-align {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container form-block">
  <div class="f-align">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="30">Text data</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="f-align margin-left">
    Please follow these instructions when entering data into the textarea to the left. Blah blah blah..
  </div>
</div>
```

I have edited your code as you want. Please check hope this will help.

Comment: I notice that you also wrapped the textarea inside a div. Why is that important?